# Why am I not being able to extract data into my HTML file using append function in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

For some reason I can not seem to be able to extract data from URL to my html file using JQUERY. Please help me. I am till a beginner

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT4XG.png)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> my program </title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="type/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
url:"My "
 }).then(function(data) {

          for(i = 0;i<data.articles.length; i++)

      {

             $('#list').append(data.articles[i].title+"<br/>");
         $('#list').append(data.articles[i].author+"<br/>");
         $('#list').append(data.articles[i].urlToImage+"<br/>");
         $('#list').append(data.articles[i].url+"<br/>");
         $('#list').append(data.articles[i].publishedAt+"<br/>");
         $('#list').append(data.articles[i].description+"<br/>"+"<hr/>");
     }
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
<p id="list">title</p>
<p id="list">author</p>
<p id="list">url</p>
<p id="list">description</p>
<p id="list">publishedAt</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

[This is the result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkorF.png)
This is the result I get in browser:

title

author

url

description

publishedAt

I am unable to extract the data for title, author and so on into my html file.

[This is the type of result I am trying to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHYch.jpg)

Comment: post your results and code here

Comment: Can you confirm your `$.ajax` request is returning valid JSON?

Comment: Please post your code here, as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Do not post images of code or errors!](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Please share your code snippet here in stead of screenshots of the code

Answer (score 1):

Ids have to be unique in html. Since your p-tags have the same id, jquery will probably select just one of them - maybe the first one or maybe the last one. This might not be what you want.

So my advice is to first rename the id in a unique way.

Assuming the data has a populated array of object, try

// HTML

```
<div id="list"></div>
```

// JS

```
// having this dataset

var data = {
    articles: [
        {
            title: 'title 1',
            author: 'author 1',
            urlToImage: 'urlToImage 1',
            url: 'url 1',
            publishedAt: 'publishedAt 1',
            description: 'description 1'
        },

        {
            title: 'title 2',
            author: 'author 2',
            urlToImage: 'urlToImage 2',
            url: 'url 2',
            publishedAt: 'publishedAt 2',
            description: 'description 2'
        }
    ]
}

var i; 


for(i = 0; i< data.articles.length; i++ ){

    var section  = data.articles[i].title + "<br>";
        section += data.articles[i].author + "<br>";
        section += data.articles[i].urlToImage + "<br>";
        section += data.articles[i].url + "<br>";
        section += data.articles[i].publishedAt + "<br>";
        section += data.articles[i].description + "<br> <hr>";
    $('#list').append(section);

}
```

Comment: That's only part of the problem. The OP has only one set of `<p>` elements, but is looping through an array of data. Hence only the values of the last set will be displayed. Some cloning/appending logic is required here too

Comment: .. and that's assuming the AJAX request is even working. The OP has absolutely no debugging detail, or even an error.